# Can React Native app use Flutter module (3rd party AAR Android)

Tags: android, react-native, flutter

I want to create 3rd party module for React Native app. The module is written in Flutter.
Flutter module (AAR) -> Flutter engine -> Android module (AAR) -> Bridge -> React Native app